# Where to find 'Click here to add new document' in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I'm trying to change the welcome sentence in my module running on odoo 8. By default it's "Click here to add new document". How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what module are you looking for doing the change.

Inherit the module's view i.e. the `external_id` by going into the debug menu and selecting `Manage views`

the code to do it in a new module is the following. eg.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
    <field name="name">Courses</field>
    <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first course(Your message here)
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

and if its of some existing module then inherit that module by

```
    <record model="external_id" id="course_list_action">
        <field name="name">Courses</field>
        <field name="res_model">(inherited model)</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="external_id"/>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html" position="inside">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first course
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```